# Big $O$ and Big $\Theta$ proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

Use definitions to prove:

If *f* and *g* are nonnegative, and f(n)=$\Theta$(h(n)) and g(n)=$O$(h(n)),

then f(n)+g(n)=$\Theta$(h(n))

I know that

f(n)=$\Theta$(h(n)) means that c|h(n)| <= |f(n) | <= d|h(n)| for some c and d,

and that

g(n)=$O$(h(n)) means that |g(n)|<=d|h(n)| for some d,

But I don't know where to go from there.

Answer (score 0):

For the $\Omega$ bound, note that if

$c|h(n)| \leq f(n)$, then $c|h(n)| \leq f(n) + g(n)$.

For the $O$ bound, note that if

$f(n) \leq c_0|h(n)|$ for all $n \geq n_0$ and $g(n) \leq c_1|h(n)|$ for all $n \geq n_1$, then

$f(n) + g(n) \leq (c_0 + c_1)|h(n)|$ for all $n \geq max(n_0, n_1)$

Comment: Did you mean $\Theta$ instead of $\Omega$ ?

Comment: No I didn't. The idea here being that if you have that $f(n) + g(n) \in \Omega(n)$ and $f(n) + g(n) \in O(n)$, you get $f(n) + g(n) \in \Theta(n)$